# Margin between 3 equal width divs(responsive)

Tags: html, css

I have three divs with equal width and the third div to expand to full width below a breakpoint (991px to be exact) and all the divs stack upon each other when browser width is below 767px, and now i want equal margins(between divs & at the edges) so please let me know a way out. And I want to achieve this without any frameworks i,e just with the help of css.

Here's the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
div[class|=col] {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 15px;
}
.title {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
#Title1 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#Title2 {
  background-color: white;
}
#Title3 {
  background-color: green;
}
p {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: black;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 ">
    <section id="Title1" class="title">Chicken</section>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <section id="Title2" class="title">Beef</section>

    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
    <section id="Title3" class="title">Sushi</section>

    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about what you'd like? You are asking for equal spacing between each element at all breakpoints, only when they are vertically aligned, only when they are horizontally aligned, etc.? Also also what amount of spacing do you want?

Comment: Sorry if I have failed to properly state my requirements.                                   -I want to equal spacing across the elements at all breakpoints.                        -Any amount of space for the spacing is quite OK for me until, they behave in accordance with the width of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add classes to the 3 div's: div-1, div-2, div-3

```
@media only screen and (max-width:766px) {
     .div-1.div-2.div-3 {
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
}
```

Like this you can add margin's for a particular resolution as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. On the contrary, the margin-bottom works well but the when i try to give margin between the divs they wrap around to the next line. So please let me know a way out.